# How to handle keyPressEvent Escape and Ctrl+C at the same time (PySide)?

Tags: python, qt, pyside

In a Pyside program, I want to use Ctrl+C for copy in my tableWidget.

I added a short-cut in QtDesigner, but it not works.

In mainGui.py

```
self.actionCopy.setShortcut(QtGui.QApplication.translate("mainDialog", "Ctrl+C", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
```

I found the key is captured by overridden keyPressEvent (just for Escape at first).
It could capture single "Key_Control" but cannot capture Ctrl+C.
Below is my code:

```
def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    # Re-direct ESC key to closeEvent
    print(event)
    if event.key() == Qt.Key_Escape:
        self.close()
    elif event.key() == QKeySequence.Copy:
        self.actionCopy.trigger()
```

How could I do to make it capture Ctrl+C or let it pass to QtDesigner's short-cut

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to override the keyPressEvent. You started good with the shortcut but I need more code to tell you where you went wrong. The workflow should be:

1. Create an action from Ctrl+C
2. Connect that action with a function of you main widget
3. In the function of your main widget that is connected with the Ctrl+C you gather all the information you need and place them in the clipboard.

But, as I said, I need more code so I can detect the problem.

*Update*:

After line 68 in your code, add the line:

```
self.tableWidget.addAction(self.actionCopy)
```

You have to add the action to the `tableWidget` also, not just to the main window.

Comment: Because it's a QDialog, I use the keyPressEvent is for capture "ESC" key for closing some connected devices. But it also captures the "Control" key event. Or it would be better to create another QAction for ESC key?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/0e66cgPC for Main program and http://pastebin.com/H1nHjyv3 for GUI

Comment: Yes, it works! Sorry for the late reply. BTW, do you know how to add action to the tableWidget in QtDesigner? I add it manually right now.

Comment: No, sorry :( I never used Qt designer, always created the GUI from the code.

Answer (score 3):

this code will readable

```
if QKeySequence(event.key()+int(event.modifiers())) == QKeySequence("Ctrl+C"):
    self.actionCopy.trigger()
```